# Angle conversion from degrees to radians via 3,14 fails

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert an angle but when it "converts" the angle the output always shows the value zero.

Here there is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // Variabili
  int angolo;
  float radianti;

  // Inserimento variabile angolo + conversione e controllo valore 
  // compreso tra 0 e 360
  cout<<"Inserisci il valore dell'angolo (deve essere compreso tra 0 e 
   360):";
  cin>>angolo;
  if(angolo > 0 && angolo < 360)
  {
   radianti=(angolo*3,14)/180;
    cout<<"Il valore in radianti dell'angolo è:"<<radianti;
  }else
  {
    cout<<"Errore l'angolo non è compreso tra 0 e 360!";
  } 
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `3,14` -> `3.14`

Comment: the comma operator strikes again

Comment: Have you tried radianti=(angolo*3,14)/180,0;
?

Comment: Sadly, source code cannot be localized. Floating point literals must be written with a dot `.`, not a comma `,`.

Comment: @Peter I think that will also fail because of the comma operator.

Comment: `3,14` -> `M_PI`, after including math header.

Comment: Thanks! Very noob at this lol. Solved with changing 3,14 with 3.14. Thanks again

Comment: @Yunnosch While symbolic constants like that are commonly put in `<cmath>` (or `<math.h>`) they are not actually defined in the standards.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, will add that to answer.

Comment: A friendly hint by a fellow non-native English speaker. Should you ever have problems getting an answer to (more complicated) questions, consider translating every identifier in your code to English. While the logic of the code theoretically is also there in any language, serving the communication habits of the readers will lower the treshold for helping.

Comment: @StoryTeller Fortunately, source code cannot be localized. Floating point literals must be written with a dot `.`, not a comma `,`.

Comment: @YSC - Whether it's sad or fortunate is debatable. Other than that, I don't see a point responding to me with my own comment. That's just tedious.

Comment: @StoryTeller well, that was precisely an effort on my part to show it is equally sad and fortunate. A stylistic device if you want. Not meant to be rude or anything.

Comment: @YSC - No offence taken. But it looks like a [FTFY](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/fixed-that-for-you-ftfy) comment, at a glance.

Comment: @StoryTeller Ho ... now I get it. Daily reminder how hard it is to convey nuance in a short written sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The result of zero is caused by the fact that you always calculate 14/180 in integer. This is caused by the evil `,` operator, which will calculate with only the part afterwards. The `angolo*3` is calculated (or not, with optimisation), but operator precedence afterwards causes the 14 to be used.
Using `3.14` instead of `3,14` will fix this.

I propose to also use an appropriate symbol and as a bonus get better precision.
E.g. (one example where to get one, others can probably be found in the comments below):

```
#include <math.h>
/* ... */
radianti=(angolo*M_PI)/180;
```

Note that this, strictly speaking, is not absolutely portable.
Make sure that this feature is provided by your target environment(s), then it is worth using. Otherwise use the `.`.
I feel with you, in being used to decimal commas instead of decimal points.

Comment: Maybe you should also explain *why* OP is always getting 0. Also, consider adding [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6.aspx) as a workaround for a specific platform.

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks. Actually I was already editing to explain.

Comment: @Bob__ The link seems quite useful for anything in the MSVC development environment, thanks.

Comment: Much better to use a portable location for the constant, such as from [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/constants.html). Note that boost even includes 2π/360 as the constant "degree".